# How to append a part of query in procedure?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I am moving my queries written in Java code to procedure. In a scenario, depending on fulfillment of a condition, a part of query is appended in the same. How I can achieve the same in stored procedure in PL/SQL?

Example:

```
String query = "select * from employee where employee_id =5";
if(true)//some condition
  query.append(" AND first_name ='pankaj'");
```

The result should be like:

```
query= "select * from employee where employee_id =5 AND first_name ='pankaj'"
```

Comment: you need to write dynamic sql query and use execute immediate to execute it. sample code link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/native-dynamic-sql

Answer (score 1):

You should use execute immediate for this purpose, it allows you to dynamically create a query string and then executing it. Here is a link to the documentation of this command - 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getEmployees(
  in_useWhere  IN NUMBER,
  out_cursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN out_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE  employee_id = 5
  AND    ( in_useWhere = 0 OR firstname = 'pankaj' );
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Or if you want to specify the `employee_id` and (optional) `first_name` to get:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getEmployees(
  in_employee_id IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
  in_firstName   IN EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
  out_cursor     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN out_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE  employee_id = in_employee_id
  AND    ( in_firstName IS NULL OR first_name = in_firstName );
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: Definitely a more elegant solution than using execute immediate, I say go for this one.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL the string append operator is `||` (two pipe characters). Thus, the PL/SQL equivalent of your code is

```
DECLARE
  query  VARCHAR2(1000) := 'SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 5';
BEGIN
  IF some_condition = TRUE THEN
    query := query || ' AND FIRST_NAME = ''pankaj''';
  END IF;
END;
```

Best of luck.